# Error while installing Nokia Suite

Tags: 13.10, dependencies

Dependency is not satisfiable *gambas2-runtime* (>=1.9.48) error while installing Nokia Suite. What should I do?

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. Please recommend me a software application similar to Nokia PC Suite for connecting my PC through Nokia Mobile.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

gambas2-runtime is in the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 12.04. For later versions of Ubuntu Gambas2 has been updated to (superseded by) Gambas3. If this doesn't work, you could try installing Nokia Suite on a Windows PC if you have one. [Nokia Support Discussions for Nokia Suite](http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?filter=labels&q=Nokia+Suite) is mainly for Windows users.

You can connect your Nokia phone in Ubuntu using *wvdial* from the Ubuntu Software Center. For information about how to connect your Nokia phone using  wvdial see this step-by-step tutorial: [Connect your Nokia phone with Linux without PC Suite](http://tareqalam.com/2008/07/11/connect-your-nokia-phone-with-linux-without-pc-suite/).

All of the steps in the tutorial have to be run from the terminal. To open the terminal use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. The terminal commands in the tutorial are highlighted in red letters. For example to run the first command in the tutorial, connect your Nokia phone to your computer via data cable, open the terminal and type:

```
lsusb
```

This command will list all USB devices that are connected to your computer. You can identify your Nokia phone by looking for a line in the output of `lsusb` that has something like the string `Nokia Mobile` in it.

The third command in the tutorial is:

```
wvdialconf create
```

If you have already installed wvdial then you can run the preceding command without installing anything else, but this command will not run properly in Ubuntu 13.10, so substitute the following command for it instead:

```
sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf
```

This will create a file named *wvdial.conf* in your /etc directory.

The last command in the tutorial is:

```
sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

This command will not run properly in Ubuntu 13.10, so you have to run the following two commands instead, which will allow you to use Gedit for editing the wvdial.conf file in Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

It is basically the same command as in the tutorial, only you have to substitute `gksudo` for `sudo` to open Gedit from the terminal, because Gedit is a graphical application.

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later gksu has been discontinued so use this command instead:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list &>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I am listing out some apps to manage Mobile Phones in Ubuntu below. Hope these help you in connecting your phone to your PC.

Gammu/Wammu - Wammu is a program to manage data in your cell phone such as contacts, calendar or messages.

- List of supported phones: http://wammu.eu/phones/
- Homepage: http://wammu.eu/wammu/
- Ubuntu App: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wammu/

gMobileMedia - gMobileMedia is a simple gtk application used to browse and handle a mobile phone filesystem, it can handle phones with more than one memory area.

- Homepage: http://gmobilebrowser.sourceforge.net/
- Ubuntu App: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gmobilemedia/

Series60-Remote - Series60-Remote is an application to manage your mobile phone. You can send and receive SMS messages directly on your computer. It also provides a complex contact and file management.

- Homepage: http://sourceforge.net/projects/series60-remote/
- Ubuntu App: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/series60-remote/

Gnokii/Gnocky - Gnocky is a mobile phone manager that let's you edit your cellphone addressbook, send SMS and draw a new logo.

- Supported hardware and configurations known to work - http://wiki.gnokii.org/index.php/Config
- Homepage: http://wiki.gnokii.org/index.php/Gnocky
- Ubuntu App: http://www.getdeb.net/software/Gnocky

AirDroid - Manage your Android from a web browser, all over the air.

- Homepage: http://www.airdroid.com/
- Review: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/android-airdroid-wireless.html